# Android: MVP. Right way to communicaticate between components

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, callback, mvp

I have implemented MVP pattern in my application. 
I have an additional layer which I call `Repository`, which is responsible for running `HTTP` asynchronous requests. I have created `OnTaskCompleteListener` interface for communication between `Repository` and `Model` (`Model` implements `OnTaskCompleteListener`). So when Repository finishes the request, it calls a method in Model and updates data. Then, Model calls a method in Presenter with the same mechanism, to let it know that Model has been updated.
What I am worrying, is the chain of callbacks that comes from `Repository` up to `Presenter`.
Is there a better way to communicate between components of MVP or is it the way to go? 
I did try "EventBus", but a large number of needed interfaces scared me off.
Observer did not seem fit as there is only one listener for each component (Model listens to Repository, Presenter listens to Model).
Thank you.

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi Quite a useful article. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive reading, I came to a conclusion, that I do not need another class 'Repository' to delegate loading of data. The model actually should be responsible for **loading and holding data**. 
Using a callback method parameter for the method of the presenter, that calls a method that loads data in the model is a great way to communicate between model and presenter.

Presenter.java

```
@Override
public void loadData(){
    mModel.loadData(new Callback{
        void onSuccess(){
            getView().notifyDataLoaded();
        }

        void onError(){
            getView().notifyErrorOccured();
        }
});
```

This way model, presenter and view are linked in this single method in very clear and intuitive manner.
Hope this will help someone.